# Cypress Test timeout on then() not respecting timeout option

Tags: cypress

I've been trying to figure out when the .then() function in Cypress is not respecting the timeout option. The then() function is asserting a few times and ultimately fails because my call is still waiting for results. What I was hoping for is setting it to 90000 so that it just spends more time asserting.

```
commonPage
    .getSearchInput()
    .clear({ force: true })
    .type('My Search Term', { force: true })
    .type('{enter}')
    .then({ timeout: 90000,  }, () => {
      accountRoles.getLabel().should('have.contain.text', 'My Search Term');
    });

  getLabel(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {
    return cy.get('div[col-id="label"]');
  }
```

Comment: What does this `accountRoles.getLabel()` translates into?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to increase the timeout for `.should('contain.text', 'My Search Term')`, putting it on the `.then()` wrapping is incorrect.

The `.should()` will retry only the `.getLabel()`, so whatever is in there needs the timeout option.

One of the down-sides of using page objects in Cypress.

---

For example, this is the usual pattern

```js
cy.get('div[col-id="label"]', {timeout:90000})
  .should('contain.text', 'My Search Term')
```

This will repeat `cy.get('div[col-id="label"]'` until `.should('contain.text', 'My Search Term')` becomes true, or times out.

Comment: But it will always find the label because the label will always exist. I need it to wait for the data to populate the field label then continue.

Comment: Of course it will wait, because you have `.should('have.contain.text', 'My Search Term')`. The test won't pass until that is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is sending a request/call, intercept that and wait on it so you don't have to continuously play a guessing game with a `timeout`. Also, 90 seconds is a lot of time to complete for what looks to be search suggestions.

```js
cy.intercept('GET','/your-call').as('yourCall')
commonPage
    .getSearchInput()
    .clear({ force: true })
    .type('My Search Term', { force: true })
    .type('{enter}')

cy.wait('@yourCall')
accountRoles.getLabel().should('have.contain.text', 'My Search Term')
```